# Grub - boot debian iso file from ntfs partition and install it

Tags: debian, boot, grub2, ntfs, iso

I have problem installing debian directly from hard drive. Say, i have a logical partition `/dev/sda5` and there is debian DVD iso file located in `(hd0,5)/iso/debian-8.0.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso` with `initrd` file there too. Then I created grub menu entry with this:

```
menuentry "Debian Jessie (stable)" {
    set isofile='/iso/debian-8.0.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso'
    set initrdfile='/iso/debian-8.0.0-hdd.initrd.gz'
    loopback loop (hd0,5)$isofile
    linux (loop)/install.amd/vmlinuz iso-scan/ask_second_pass=true iso-scan/filename=$isofile
    initrd (hd0,5)$initrdfile
}
```

Booting is successful. But, when come to searching debian CD it fails. The iso file cannot be found by installer. If I use USB drive, every thing goes fine. In USB, I put debian DVD iso in `/boot/iso/debian-8.0.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso'. And the menuentry look like this:

```
menuentry 'Debian Jessie (stable)' {
    set isofile='/boot/iso/debian-8.0.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso'
    set initrdfile='/boot/iso/debian-8.0.0-amd64-DVD-1.hdd.initrd.gz'
    loopback loop $isofile
    linux (loop)/install.amd/vmlinuz iso-scan/ask_second_pass=true iso-scan/filename=$isofile
    initrd $initrdfile
}
```

My `/dev/sda5` is formatted in `NTFS` and my USB drive is formatted in `FAT32`. So, I guess the problem is because of filesystem format. And if it is, how can I boot debian iso file properly from NTFS partition?

**Update**

The NTFS partiton is logical partition. Is it causeing problem too?

Comment: From [this related thread in ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1549847), you may have to insert additional modules in the menuentry, such as `insmod ntfs`.

Comment: Not working. The install still can't detect iso image file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need download `initrd.gz` from [hd-media directory](https://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/dists/stable/main/installer-amd64/current/images/hd-media/) and put it in the same directory with the image file and give it a suitable name.
For example my `grub.cfg`

```
menuentry 'Debian Jessie (stable) graphical expert' {
    set isofile='/iso/debian-8.3.0-amd64-lxde-CD-1.iso'
    set initrdfile='/iso/gtk/debian-8.3.0-amd64-lxde-CD-1.initrd.gz'
    loopback loop $isofile
    linux (loop)/install.amd/vmlinuz findiso=$isofile dekstop=lxde priority=low     gfxpayload=1024x768x32
    initrd $initrdfile
}
```

I find solution in Reddit
and [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive#Debian)

Answer (score 1):

You must download the **hd-media/vmlinuz** and **hd-media/initrd.gz** and use them as the Linux kernel and initial ramdisk respectively. You can't use the **vmlinuz** and **initrd.gz** inside the Debian ISO image. The Debian ISO image is the CD the installer ask for.

Here's a detailed guide on my blog : https://www.linuxbabe.com/debian/boot-debian-9-iso-from-hard-drive-grub2

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Unix & Linux. Linking to a blog or similar for background and more information is fine, but if you are linking to your own site, you definitely need to be explicit about it.  See [How not to be a spammer.](/help/promotion)

Comment: @tripleee Just edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Debian 8 (jessie), you need different options to find the iso image (the option you specified are valid for Ubuntu).

Change your grub entry as follows:

```
linux (loop)/install.amd/vmlinuz findiso=$isofile
```